Postgres connection URL options stopped working switching from PG11 to PG14
I have a codebase that relies on a connection to Postgres via a full self-contained connection URL. The Python codebase was working while on PG11 but after switching to PG14 the options in the connection URL are no longer recognized:
postgresql://username:password@host:port/database?&options=-csearch_path=my_schema&target_session_attrs=read-write&connect_timeout=5

specifically this part: ?&options=-csearch_path=my_schema&target_session_attrs=read-write&connect_timeout=5
The search_path is not recognized and therefore the schema my_schema is not set by default.
I have tried many possibilities including, but none seem to work:

adding encoding to the space like ?&options=-c%20search_path=my_schema
removing the leading & before the options
removing the -c before search_path
specifying search_path without options


You must have made a mistake. That URI is syntactically incorrect and won't work with any version of PostgreSQL. The problems are

?& right after the database name, when it should be only ?

= in the first parameter value, when you have to URI-escape that to %3D


Besides, port is not a valid port number. I assume that you modified the actual URI before you posted it, which is a bad idea, because it may well hide some of your actual mistakes.
